# Why does -reconnect create new session on localhost?

Tags: session, ssl, openssl, localhost

I run two commands:

1) `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -reconnect`

2) `openssl s_client -connect 10.102.113.3:443 -reconnect`

When I run the first command, the `-reconnect` option does not reuse the older session. However, when I run the second command, the `-reconnect` option reuses the previous session as it is expected to.

Why doesn't the `-reconnect` option work with `localhost`?

Comment: Your title says it does, your text says it doesn't. Which is it?

Comment: @EJP, `-reconnect` creates only `new sessions` on localhost. It reuses sessions only when I give an external IP.
Sorry for the blunder.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I suggest that the session is defined by its local and remote IP addresses and ports, so changing one of them must give you a new session.